# awk? for output of nmap scan

Tags: awk, grep, cut, nmap

I am working on a script to parse nmap output to grab vulnerable systems and the IP address of it.

**nmap content looks like this:**

```
    Nmap scan report for 10.x.x.x
    Host is up (-0.031s latency).

    PORT    STATE SERVICE
    445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
    MAC Address: 00:50:56:89:6E:4B (VMware)

    Host script results:
    | smb-vuln-cve2009-3103: 
    |   VULNERABLE:
    |   SMBv2 exploit (CVE-2009-3103, Microsoft Security Advisory 975497)
    |     State: VULNERABLE
    |     IDs:  CVE:CVE-2009-3103
    |           Array index error in the SMBv2 protocol implementation in srv2.sys in Microsoft Windows Vista Gold, SP1, and SP2,
    |           Windows Server 2008 Gold and SP2, and Windows 7 RC allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a
    |           denial of service (system crash) via an & (ampersand) character in a Process ID High header field in a NEGOTIATE
```

**Looking for output like this (if possible):**

```
    10.x.x.x
    SMBv2 exploit (CVE-2009-3103, Microsoft Security Advisory 975497)
    State: VULNERABLE

    Next Entry...

    Next Entry...
```

Any ideas how to do so??? I appreciate your time in looking at this...

Comment: You can't get the output you posted from the input you posted and you didn't post any attempt to solve it yourself so expect downvotes and eventual closure. See [ask] then try again.

Comment: I appreciate the nudge to correct the post. I've been creating a master script in bash to scan targets and output content into directories for easy grab and go (shares, host list, service vulnerability search through firefox, etc...) ...From what I can tell, the usage of awk to grab by columns OR change the output into xml might be a better route to go. Again, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Nmap 7.50 or newer, you can add `--script-args vulns.short` to your command and the output will be shortened to:

```
| smb-vuln-cve2009-3103: 
|_  10.x.x.x VULNERABLE CVE-2009-3103
```

This is much easier to parse, since all of the necessary info is on one line.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I saw this solution as well and perhaps, this is the easiest route to go. Thanks mate!